# another asp.net routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I searched around for my problem, but could not find a solution...

I have a BlogController, and I want to match the following routes to a separate action:

```
/blog/
/blog/rss
/blog/tags/tagName
```

However, I want to match any other url's, like:

```
/blog/my-post
/blog/other-post
```

to the Post action.

I tried with

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog",
"blog/{action}/{param}",
new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("BlogPost",
"blog/{slug}",
new { controller = "Blog", action = "post" });
```

but the second route is never matched.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first route allready match any urls in the form of `blog/slug`.

Whe resolving routes, ASP.NET MVC will try use the first match, and even if there is no action to get that method. ASP.NET MVC's routing still won't try the next route.

So with your routes, the url `blog/my-first-article` will match the first url and MVC will look for the `my-first-action` method on the `BlogController` class.

**Solution 1**

You could either define seperate routes for each method, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog index",
    "blog",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute("Blog RSS feed",
    "blog/rss",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Rss" });

routes.MapRoute("Posts by tag",
    "blog/Tags/{params}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Tags" });

routes.MapRoute("BlogPost",
    "blog/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "post" });
```

**Solution 2**

You could use a constraint to define valid values for `{action}` in the first route.

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog",
    "blog/{action}/{param}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { action = 'index|rss|tags' });

routes.MapRoute("BlogPost",
    "blog/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "post" });
```

The constraint is in form of a regex.

Comment: Arjan, thanks for the update! For solution 1, I thought about that, but I didn't liked to hardcode each route, for each controller. Solution 2, on the other hand, is EXACTLY what I had in mind. Thanks!